# Why some people chain the parameters of two different networks and train them with same optimizer?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, generative-adversarial-network

I was looking at CycleGAN's official pytorch implementation and there, author chained the parameters of both networks and used a single optimizer for both network. How does this work? Is it better than using two different optimizers for two different networks ?

```
all_params = chain(module_a.parameters(), module_b.parameters())
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(all_params)
```

Answer (score 5):

From `chain` documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain

```
itertools.chain(*iterables)

    Make an iterator that returns elements from the first iterable until it is exhausted, then proceeds to the next iterable, until all of the iterables are exhausted.
```

As `parameters()` gives you an iterable, you can use the optimizer to simultaneously optimize parameters for both of the networks. So, same optimizer states will be used for both models (`Modules`), if you use two different optimizers, the parameters will be optimized separately.

If you have a composite network, it becomes necessary to optimize the parameters (of all) at the same time, hence using a single optimizer for all of them is the way to go.

Comment: This seems like a restatement of OP's question. The OP seems to understand that the same optimizer is used to optimize parameters of both networks but is asking how that works and why not use two optimizers.

Comment: so if we use single optimizer, does loss values of model B affect the change in model A ?

Comment: Yes, if you use the same for both models, it also depends on how the loss is defined.

Comment: won't that sabotage the training of generative networks in cycle GAN ?

Comment: ```self.loss_G = self.loss_G_A + self.loss_G_B + self.loss_cycle_A + self.loss_cycle_B + self.loss_idt_A + self.loss_idt_B

self.loss_G.backward()```    Here it sums all the losses of both generators and optimize them. I feel different optimizers should be used and losses should not be added

Comment: Sorry, I'm not actually very familiar with the cyclegan implementation, will be back after looking into that.

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense to optimize both generators together (and adding both losses), because of the "cycle". The cycle loss uses both generators - `G_B(G_A(A))` and `G_A(G_B(B))`. I think, if you would use separate optimizers you would need to call `backward()` on both losses before calling `step()` to achieve the same effect (this not have to be true for all optimization algorithms).

In official code, parameters of discriminator are also chained, but you could easily use separate optimizers (again, it not have to be true for other optimizations algorithms) because loss of D_A do not depend on D_B.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the official repo Issues.

https://github.com/junyanz/pytorch-CycleGAN-and-pix2pix/issues?q=is%3Aissue+optimizer+is%3Aclosed

https://github.com/junyanz/pytorch-CycleGAN-and-pix2pix/issues/177

https://github.com/junyanz/pytorch-CycleGAN-and-pix2pix/issues/1381

Good luck.